# Modify an integer value in a textfile in C

Tags: c, file

Lets say I have a text file like this:

```
106
60
107
50
108
37
```

So the 106 107 and 108 are my IDs and the 60, 50 and 37 are stock quantities. And I want to modify the stock quantities like let's say Iadd 30 more to ID:106, so it should be 60+30=90. So my question is, how should I code it so it updates the text file.

I have already tried to scan the file into an array but it doesn't seem to scan the data into the array:

```
while(fscanf(filename, "%d", array[i]))
{
    i++;
}
```

I tried that method and it doesn't seem to work. Is there any alternatives with this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: But anyway: you cannot update a text file directly unless the new number has the same number of digits than the old number. In other words, you cannot _insert_ characters into a text file directly. What you can do is for example read the whole text file into memory, change it there and the write the whole text file from scratch.

Comment: Oh, and it should be `while (fscanf(filename, "%d", array[i]) != EOF)`.

Comment: Your loop should be more like this: `while(fscanf(fileptr, "%d", &array[i]) == 1)` assuming you have an array of `int` and not pointers. First parameter should also be the `FILE*` you got from opening the file and not some filename.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily modify the text file in place because you might need to insert bytes as the numbers grow to more digits.

You should use loop to read the file and write updated contents to a new file:

```
int update_file(FILE *in, FILE *out, int ref, int delta) {
    int id, quantity;
    int res = 0;

    while (fscanf(in, "%d%d", &id, &quantity) == 2) {
        if (id == ref) {
            quantity += delta;
            res++;
        }
        fprintf(out, "%d\n%d\n", id, quantity);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: why ==2? That's the part i dont understand

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. There are 2 numbers per item, if one is missing, the file format is incorrect (`scanf()` returned `0` or `1`) or end of file has been reached (`scanf` returned `EOF`).